# Popup window in elementor with custom image from woocommerce / ACF

Tags: javascript, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

I need a custom image in my woocommerce and have created a custom field for this.
Would like to display a custom image in a popup which is activated via shortcode from the category page.

The problem is that the popup window shows the same image.
Only if I refresh or go to a new page does the correct image appear.

Have disabled cache.

I use the following code:

```
add_action( 'acf/include_fields', function() {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'acf_add_local_field_group' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    acf_add_local_field_group( array(
        'key' => 'group_651084a533850',
        'title' => 'Billede til næringsindhold',
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'field_651084a6013c4',
                'label' => 'Nærings indhold',
                'name' => 'n-indhold',
                'type' => 'image',
                'return_format' => 'array',
                'library' => 'all',
                'preview_size' => 'medium',
            ),
        ),
        'location' => array(
            array(
                array(
                    'param' => 'post_type',
                    'operator' => '!=',
                    'value' => 'shop_coupon',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'menu_order' => 0,
        'position' => 'side',
        'style' => 'default',
        'label_placement' => 'top',
        'instruction_placement' => 'label',
        'active' => true,
    ) );
} );

function display_n_indhold_shortcode() {
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $image = get_field('n-indhold', $post_id);
    if ($image) {
        return '<img src="' . esc_url($image['url']) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($image['alt']) . '">';
    }
    return '';
}
add_shortcode('n_indhold_image', 'display_n_indhold_shortcode');
```